# How do databases store and index strings?

Tags: database, indexing

Please help me understand something about DBs.

Generally (=in default configuration, no special tuning), how do databases (=oracle/mssql) store variable-length strings (=VARCHAR2), considering that row/block size is constant? I assume they store a pointer to some other data block, outside of the table rows - is it correct?

Also, how does a string index work - B-Tree that uses alphabetical order for key comparison, or something smarter like a prefix tree?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The index mechanisms used by databases is depends entirely on the database.  If you have specific questions about a database, then you should consult the documentation for the database.  I would expect most indexes to be B-Trees, but that is just a guess.

The question about storing variable length strings is also up to the database engine.  In general, these are length-encoded, so the first two bytes have the length of the string followed by the characters.  However, there is nothing in SQL that prevents other mechanisms, such as null-byte encoding (as done in C).  There is probably some database out there that stores them in this fashion.

However, this is an approximation.  Long strings in MSSQL are stored on separate data pages from the fixed length fields in the record.  When long strings exceed the page size, things are much more complicated, because the string has to fit on pages.

Databases that support text retrieval functionality have entirely different mechanisms for indexing strings -- typically an inverted index.

If you are looking for the best way to solve a problem, then you should describe the problem in another question.  If you are looking for specifics about a database, then Google, the database documention, and Wikipedia are your best friends.